# Expo React Native: Cannot use import statement outside a module in app.config.ts

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm working on a React Native project using Expo, and I'm trying to set different server URLs based on whether the application is running on an emulator or a real device. I have been attempting to do this in my `app.config.ts` file by importing `expo-constants` and `expo-device`. However, I'm getting a SyntaxError, saying `Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

More of my use case: I have a local docker running which i am using as dev environement. I am able to access the localhost address from my emulator with the address 10.0.2.2. However, I am still lacking the functionalitity to access the localhost address from my real device. It should automatically adjust the apiUrl to reflect that use case. Currently, I am trying to use the `expo-device` package to detect if it is an emulator or a real device, and use `expo-constants` to get the current IPv4 address of the host.

I am not quite sure how to import the necessary packages and use them inside `app.config.ts`.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import Device from "expo-device";

let supabaseUrl: string;
let anonKey: string;
let bucket: string;

const uri = `http://${Constants.manifest?.debuggerHost
  ?.split(":")
  ?.shift()}:54321`;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  supabaseUrl = Device.isDevice ? uri : "http://10.0.2.2:54321";
  anonKey =
    "anonKey_dev";
  bucket = "bucket-dev";
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "staging") {
  supabaseUrl = "https://project.supabase.co";
  anonKey =
    "anonKey_staging";
  bucket = "bucket-staging";
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  supabaseUrl = "https://project.supabase.co";
  anonKey =
    "anonKey_prod";
  bucket = "bucket-prod";
}

module.exports = {
  {//other modules}
  extra: {
    supabaseUrl,
    anonKey,
    bucket,
  },
};
```

I already tried importing it with require() but this did not work either.

Here is the error I am recieving:

```
SyntaxError: Error reading Expo config at C:\Users\user\Development\Project\app.config.ts:

Cannot use import statement outside a module
C:\Users\user\Development\Project\node_modules\expo-constants\build\Constants.js:1
import { CodedError, NativeModulesProxy } from 'expo-modules-core';
```

Any help is highly appreciated.